# is Microsoft sort.exe able to sort unicode UTF-16 (LE) files?

Tags: shell, sorting, command-line

Is Microsoft sort.exe 5.1.2600.0 (xpclient.010817-1148) able to sort UTF-16 (LE) files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort.exe has a number of limitations that can make it somewhat difficult to use.  For example, although sort.exe appears to read UTF-16 (LE) files okay, it appears to output files using the current locale settings.